# how to plot isochrone_map around a particular node?

Tags: python, osmnx

I'm working on the followimg map data:

```
# Define the bounding box coordinates for the region of interest
north, south, east, west = 40.8580, 40.7448, -73.9842, -74.2996

# Retrieve the street network for the region of interest
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(north, south, east, west, network_type='drive')
```

how to first randomly choose a point inside the map, and then plot the isochrone map within 1.5km away from it?

I've tried to follow the tutoria; [here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/main/notebooks/13-isolines-isochrones.ipynb) but it crashed at `center_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, x[0], y[0])` with  an error like `ImportError: scikit-learn must be installed to search an unprojected graph` and installing or importing scikit-learn further show another error with numpy!
I have also difficulty in selecting a random point insdie the map? how to odo that?

```
!pip install osmnx
!pip install --upgrade numpy


import osmnx as ox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# Define the bounding box coordinates for the region of interest
north, south, east, west = 40.8580, 40.7448, -73.9842, -74.2996

# Retrieve the street network for the region of interest
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(north, south, east, west, network_type='drive')

# Select a random node from the street network
node = np.random.choice(list(G.nodes))



import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

%matplotlib inline
ox.__version__


# find the centermost node and then project the graph to UTM
gdf_nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, edges=False)
x, y = gdf_nodes["geometry"].unary_union.centroid.xy
center_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, x[0], y[0])
G = ox.project_graph(G)
```

And the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-15c0f6bcfb98> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 gdf_nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, edges=False)
      3 x, y = gdf_nodes["geometry"].unary_union.centroid.xy
----> 4 center_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, x[0], y[0])
      5 G = ox.project_graph(G)

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/osmnx/distance.py in nearest_nodes(G, X, Y, return_dist)
    214         # if unprojected, use ball tree for haversine nearest-neighbor search
    215         if BallTree is None:  # pragma: no cover
--> 216             raise ImportError("scikit-learn must be installed to search an unprojected graph")
    217         # haversine requires lat, lng coords in radians
    218         nodes_rad = np.deg2rad(nodes[["y", "x"]])

ImportError: scikit-learn must be installed to search an unprojected graph

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

Comment: Provide the complete code you are using, and the complete error traceback.

Comment: @gboeing I've added the code. But this says `scikit-learn must be installed` wheneI dod that, again it shows the exact same thing. I don't want to replicate the tutorial. All I try to obtain is an isochrone map around a random point in newyork city

Comment: You are searching for nearest nodes in an unprojected graph, and like the error says, you have to install the otherwise optional scikit-learn package to do so.

Comment: @gboeing in the toturial it just loads the map like me. What does unprojected mean? Unfortunately, After installing scikit-learn I have the same error. It does not work.  can you show me a simple example of isochrone map for newyork?